# Is the electron field of QED similar to the Higg's field?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

If I understand it (I probably don't...) the Higg's field is a field that permeates the universe, and its excitations are the Higg's bosons. It seems that this implies that the Higg's field is a property of the universe itself, and not generated by something like an electric field would be generated by charged particles.

Quantum Electro Dynamics seems to state that the electron is the excitation of the "electron field" - if this is incorrect then stop me there, of course.

Does this mean that the electron field is also some field that simply permeates the universe?  Or is the electron field somehow generated by something else?  Alternately, is the electron field a mathematical convenience without physical existence?

Comment: Nitpick:  The physicist is Peter Higgs, not Peter Higg.  So it's the "Higgs field" (with his name as a noun modifier), not the "Higg's field" (as a possessive).

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs, electron and electromagnetic fields all permeate space. In QFT their excitations are indeed what we call particles.

They are different types of fields, however. Higgs is scalar, electron in spinor, and EM is vector.

Comment: The Higgs field has another important property what distinguish it from an electron quantum field: Its vacuum expectation value is non-zero. If the  vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field were zero, the corresponding Higgs particle would be a rather "banal" particle.